# how to split array of strings, delete, and assign new array to same array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, include

I want to delete items in an array that `include('https://www.agci.org')`.
I am splitting the array first with `('>')` and then using that to search each string with the includes function. I want to delete the ones that include a url and then use the array with the deleted items and set it back to `arr[i].authors`. Idk why `spl = arr[i].authors` line isnt working when its still within the if statement/function

```
for(var i=0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++){
  var spl = arr[i].authors[0].split('>');
  spl.forEach(function(item){
    if(item.includes('https://www.agci.org')){
        delete item;
        spl = arr[i].authors
    }
    })
}

for(var i=0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++){
  var spl = arr[i].authors[0].split('>');
  spl.forEach(function(item){
    if(item.includes('https://www.agci.org')){
        result = spl.filter(item)
        arr[i].authors = result;
    }
    })
}
```

my arrays look like this. they are random arrays that i need to sort and filter through

```
arr = [
{
"post_title": "Food System Impacts of Pests & Pathogens in a Changing Climate",
"authors":
        [
            "https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/1520\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/Roz_low_res_9_11_cropped.jpg?itok=vDp_RwzD\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/1520\">Rosamond Lee Naylor>Stanford University>William Wrigley Professor of Earth System Science; Founding Director of the Center on Food Security and the Environment; Senior Fellow at the Stanford Woods Institute for the Environment and the Freeman Spogli Institute for International Studies.>https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/2354\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/Battisti.jpg?itok=82GpfOY3\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/2354\">David S Battisti>University of Washington>Tamaki Chair of Atmospheric Sciences >https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3091\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/default_images/AGCI_profile_sm.jpg?itok=7Trdel1u\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3091\">Curtis Deutsch>>>https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3092\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/Ronald.jpg?itok=Qre04udp\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3092\">Pamela Ronald>>>https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3093\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/Tewksbury.jpg?itok=gdBNWssA\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3093\">Josh Tewksbury>>"
        ]
},
{
"post_title": "Impacts of Land Use and Land Management on Earth System Evolution, Biogeochemical Cycles, Extremes and Inter-Sectoral Dynamics",
"authors":
        [
            "https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/2511\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/CalvinK_0.jpg?itok=rIidxNOX\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/2511\">Kate Calvin>Pacific Northwest National Laboratory>Earth Scientist>https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/2052\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/13S2_Hurtt.jpg?itok=iQsU00Xe\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/2052\">George Hurtt>University of Maryland>Professor>https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/2055\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/Lawrence_photo.png?itok=qCnfHCfg\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/2055\">David Lawrence>National Center for Atmospheric Research (NCAR)>Senior Scientist "
        ]
},
{
"post_title": "Advancing the Theory and Practice of Urban Heat Resilience",
"authors":
        [
            "https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3175\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/ladd-keith-sm.jpg?itok=cnW3QjGu\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3175\">Ladd Keith>University of Arizona>Assistant Professor>https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3176\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/Dave%20Hondula.jpg?itok=ewI2DCd_\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3176\">David Hondula>Arizona State University>Senior Sustainability Scientist; Associate Professor; Faculty Affiliate >https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3179\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/Hunter-Professional-Cropped-291x300.jpg?itok=etdVjEL7\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3179\">Hunter Jones>National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration>Climate and Health Projects Manager>https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/2748\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/sara%20m.jpg?itok=048o8evr\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/2748\">Sara Meerow>Arizona State University>Assistant Professor>https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3178\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/v-kelly-turner-600x800.jpg?itok=DikoBPnV\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3178\">V. Kelly Turner>University of California, Los Angeles>Assistant Professor"
        ]
},
{
"post_title": "Advancing the Theory and Practice of Urban Heat Resilience",
"authors":
        [
            "https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3175\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/ladd-keith-sm.jpg?itok=cnW3QjGu\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3175\">Ladd Keith>University of Arizona>Assistant Professor>https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3176\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/Dave%20Hondula.jpg?itok=ewI2DCd_\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3176\">David Hondula>Arizona State University>Senior Sustainability Scientist; Associate Professor; Faculty Affiliate >https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3179\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/Hunter-Professional-Cropped-291x300.jpg?itok=etdVjEL7\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3179\">Hunter Jones>National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration>Climate and Health Projects Manager>https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/2748\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/sara%20m.jpg?itok=048o8evr\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/2748\">Sara Meerow>Arizona State University>Assistant Professor>https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3178\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/v-kelly-turner-600x800.jpg?itok=DikoBPnV\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3178\">V. Kelly Turner>University of California, Los Angeles>Assistant Professor"
        ]
}

]
```

I want them to look like this but idk if theres a way to filter the author names because they include the positions as well.

```
arr = [
   {
"post_title": "Advancing the Theory and Practice of Urban Heat Resilience",
"authors": [
       Ladd Keith,David Hondula,Hunter Jones,Sara Meerow,V. Kelly Turner"
        ]
   }

]
```

Comment: `delete item` has no effect on the array, it just deletes the local variable.

Comment: Use `filter()`.

Comment: so i updated my question with the filter function but what would go in the paranthesis? @Barmar

Comment: Is there a consistent order of names and positions? Is it always `concatURL>headshotURL>contactURL>name>university>positions>`?  In that case, you could extrat the names by index rather than removing URLs by pattern matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly just a case for [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)? Here using [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

```js
const arr = [{ "post_title": "Food System Impacts of Pests & Pathogens in a Changing Climate", "authors": ["https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/1520\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/Roz_low_res_9_11_cropped.jpg?itok=vDp_RwzD\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/1520\">Rosamond Lee Naylor>Stanford University>William Wrigley Professor of Earth System Science; Founding Director of the Center on Food Security and the Environment; Senior Fellow at the Stanford Woods Institute for the Environment and the Freeman Spogli Institute for International Studies.>https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/2354\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/Battisti.jpg?itok=82GpfOY3\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/2354\">David S Battisti>University of Washington>Tamaki Chair of Atmospheric Sciences >https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3091\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/default_images/AGCI_profile_sm.jpg?itok=7Trdel1u\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3091\">Curtis Deutsch>>>https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3092\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/Ronald.jpg?itok=Qre04udp\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3092\">Pamela Ronald>>>https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3093\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/Tewksbury.jpg?itok=gdBNWssA\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3093\">Josh Tewksbury>>"] }, { "post_title": "Impacts of Land Use and Land Management on Earth System Evolution, Biogeochemical Cycles, Extremes and Inter-Sectoral Dynamics", "authors": ["https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/2511\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/CalvinK_0.jpg?itok=rIidxNOX\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/2511\">Kate Calvin>Pacific Northwest National Laboratory>Earth Scientist>https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/2052\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/13S2_Hurtt.jpg?itok=iQsU00Xe\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/2052\">George Hurtt>University of Maryland>Professor>https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/2055\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/Lawrence_photo.png?itok=qCnfHCfg\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/2055\">David Lawrence>National Center for Atmospheric Research (NCAR)>Senior Scientist "] }, { "post_title": "Advancing the Theory and Practice of Urban Heat Resilience", "authors": ["https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3175\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/ladd-keith-sm.jpg?itok=cnW3QjGu\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3175\">Ladd Keith>University of Arizona>Assistant Professor>https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3176\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/Dave%20Hondula.jpg?itok=ewI2DCd_\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3176\">David Hondula>Arizona State University>Senior Sustainability Scientist; Associate Professor; Faculty Affiliate >https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3179\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/Hunter-Professional-Cropped-291x300.jpg?itok=etdVjEL7\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3179\">Hunter Jones>National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration>Climate and Health Projects Manager>https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/2748\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/sara%20m.jpg?itok=048o8evr\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/2748\">Sara Meerow>Arizona State University>Assistant Professor>https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3178\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/v-kelly-turner-600x800.jpg?itok=DikoBPnV\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3178\">V. Kelly Turner>University of California, Los Angeles>Assistant Professor"] }, { "post_title": "Advancing the Theory and Practice of Urban Heat Resilience", "authors": ["https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3175\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/ladd-keith-sm.jpg?itok=cnW3QjGu\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3175\">Ladd Keith>University of Arizona>Assistant Professor>https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3176\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/Dave%20Hondula.jpg?itok=ewI2DCd_\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3176\">David Hondula>Arizona State University>Senior Sustainability Scientist; Associate Professor; Faculty Affiliate >https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3179\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/Hunter-Professional-Cropped-291x300.jpg?itok=etdVjEL7\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3179\">Hunter Jones>National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration>Climate and Health Projects Manager>https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/2748\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/sara%20m.jpg?itok=048o8evr\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/2748\">Sara Meerow>Arizona State University>Assistant Professor>https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3178\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/v-kelly-turner-600x800.jpg?itok=DikoBPnV\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3178\">V. Kelly Turner>University of California, Los Angeles>Assistant Professor"] }];

for (const post of arr) {
  post.authors = post.authors[0].match(/(?<=">(?!https))[^>]+/g)
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter()` to remove the URLs, then use `join()` to concatenate the remaining elements back into a string.

```js
arr = [{
    "post_title": "Food System Impacts of Pests & Pathogens in a Changing Climate",
    "authors": [
      "https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/1520\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/Roz_low_res_9_11_cropped.jpg?itok=vDp_RwzD\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/1520\">Rosamond Lee Naylor>Stanford University>William Wrigley Professor of Earth System Science; Founding Director of the Center on Food Security and the Environment; Senior Fellow at the Stanford Woods Institute for the Environment and the Freeman Spogli Institute for International Studies.>https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/2354\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/Battisti.jpg?itok=82GpfOY3\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/2354\">David S Battisti>University of Washington>Tamaki Chair of Atmospheric Sciences >https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3091\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/default_images/AGCI_profile_sm.jpg?itok=7Trdel1u\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3091\">Curtis Deutsch>>>https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3092\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/Ronald.jpg?itok=Qre04udp\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3092\">Pamela Ronald>>>https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3093\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/Tewksbury.jpg?itok=gdBNWssA\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3093\">Josh Tewksbury>>"
    ]
  },
  {
    "post_title": "Impacts of Land Use and Land Management on Earth System Evolution, Biogeochemical Cycles, Extremes and Inter-Sectoral Dynamics",
    "authors": [
      "https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/2511\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/CalvinK_0.jpg?itok=rIidxNOX\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/2511\">Kate Calvin>Pacific Northwest National Laboratory>Earth Scientist>https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/2052\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/13S2_Hurtt.jpg?itok=iQsU00Xe\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/2052\">George Hurtt>University of Maryland>Professor>https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/2055\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/Lawrence_photo.png?itok=qCnfHCfg\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/2055\">David Lawrence>National Center for Atmospheric Research (NCAR)>Senior Scientist "
    ]
  },
  {
    "post_title": "Advancing the Theory and Practice of Urban Heat Resilience",
    "authors": [
      "https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3175\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/ladd-keith-sm.jpg?itok=cnW3QjGu\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3175\">Ladd Keith>University of Arizona>Assistant Professor>https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3176\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/Dave%20Hondula.jpg?itok=ewI2DCd_\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3176\">David Hondula>Arizona State University>Senior Sustainability Scientist; Associate Professor; Faculty Affiliate >https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3179\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/Hunter-Professional-Cropped-291x300.jpg?itok=etdVjEL7\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3179\">Hunter Jones>National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration>Climate and Health Projects Manager>https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/2748\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/sara%20m.jpg?itok=048o8evr\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/2748\">Sara Meerow>Arizona State University>Assistant Professor>https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3178\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/v-kelly-turner-600x800.jpg?itok=DikoBPnV\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3178\">V. Kelly Turner>University of California, Los Angeles>Assistant Professor"
    ]
  },
  {
    "post_title": "Advancing the Theory and Practice of Urban Heat Resilience",
    "authors": [
      "https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3175\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/ladd-keith-sm.jpg?itok=cnW3QjGu\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3175\">Ladd Keith>University of Arizona>Assistant Professor>https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3176\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/Dave%20Hondula.jpg?itok=ewI2DCd_\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3176\">David Hondula>Arizona State University>Senior Sustainability Scientist; Associate Professor; Faculty Affiliate >https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3179\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/Hunter-Professional-Cropped-291x300.jpg?itok=etdVjEL7\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3179\">Hunter Jones>National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration>Climate and Health Projects Manager>https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/2748\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/sara%20m.jpg?itok=048o8evr\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/2748\">Sara Meerow>Arizona State University>Assistant Professor>https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3178\">https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/headshot/public/img-contact/v-kelly-turner-600x800.jpg?itok=DikoBPnV\">https://www.agci.org/redhen/contact/3178\">V. Kelly Turner>University of California, Los Angeles>Assistant Professor"
    ]
  }
];

arr.forEach(post => post.authors[0] = post.authors[0].split('>')
  .filter(item => !item.includes('https://www.agci.org'))
    .join(','));
    
console.log(arr);
```